# If someone becomes unconscious due to a cocktail of prescription medication, would they be held liable for holding up the flight?

Tags: legal, health

I have a friend who has travelled to the U.S, Canada, UK, and Australia a few times. He is prescribed the painkiller oxycodone (Oxycontin) by his GP and an anti-anxiety medication, diazepam (Valium) by his psychiatrist.

He says that he takes it normally but I know that he's teetering towards addiction as he now takes an added dose for sleep as well. He's taken these on flights and slept deeply as well as totally forgot his experience. Knowing that he'll build tolerance to it and have to take larger doses, I imagine there's a time that will come when hill suffer an overdose particularly as these are both CNS depressants.

If he were to take these on a flight and then become unconscious to the point where the crew couldn't arouse him from his sleep, would he get charged for disrupting the flight when he lands? I believe that a pilot would have to deviate the plane from its original destination.

Comment: This is probably more for [law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) but would probably need to be qualified at least with a country tag.

Comment: unlikely, I would assume they'd just move him off the plane at the end if need be, calling medical staff.

Comment: IANAL, if after investigation it has been found that he was negligent in the drug he was taking, then I would assume he will be charged with something.

Comment: Do you mean by "charged" a financial fee or compensation for damages, or an administrative or criminal liability?

Comment: It may be if the crew can't wake him up him that they'll declare a medical emergency and possibly divert the flight.  Also cabin crew don't like drugged out people as it becomes a safety issue for evacuation etc.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't seem to fit the focus of "travel" and is perhaps better suited for a law site.